# VBA Recordset Update Hanging On Specfic Record

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2013

So I have the below...

```
Sub test4()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim Source_rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Dest_rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

Set Source_rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCTROW [Scorecard Last Ran].[Scorecard ID], Round(([DQS - Scorecard History].[No Passed]/([DQS - Scorecard History].[No Passed]+[DQS - Scorecard History].[No Failed]))*100,1) & '%' AS Score FROM [DQS - Scorecards] INNER JOIN ((SELECT [DQS - Scorecard History].[Scorecard ID], Max([DQS - Scorecard History].[Date/Time Scorecard Ran]) AS [MaxOfDate/Time Scorecard Ran] FROM [DQS - Scorecard History] GROUP BY [DQS - Scorecard History].[Scorecard ID])  AS [Scorecard Last Ran] INNER JOIN [DQS - Scorecard History] ON ([Scorecard Last Ran].[MaxOfDate/Time Scorecard Ran] = [DQS - Scorecard History].[Date/Time Scorecard Ran]) AND ([Scorecard Last Ran].[Scorecard ID] = [DQS - Scorecard History].[Scorecard ID])) ON [DQS - Scorecards].ID = [DQS - Scorecard History].[Scorecard ID];")
Set Dest_rst = db.OpenRecordset("DQS - Scorecards")

If (Source_rst.BOF And Source_rst.EOF) Or (Dest_rst.BOF And Dest_rst.EOF) Then Exit Sub

While (Not Source_rst.EOF)
    Dest_rst.MoveFirst
    While (Not Dest_rst.EOF)
        If Dest_rst![ID] = Source_rst![Scorecard ID] And Dest_rst![ID] <> 3 Then
            Debug.Print Source_rst![Scorecard ID] & " - " & Source_rst![Score]
            Dest_rst.Edit
            Dest_rst![Score] = Source_rst![Score]
            Dest_rst.Update
            DoEvents
        End If
        Dest_rst.MoveNext
    Wend
    Source_rst.MoveNext
Wend

End Sub
```

Fairly straightforward right? Except if I remove the `Dest_rst![ID] <> 3` it hangs, even if I leave it for hours. There is nothing special about record 3, and the data going in is the same, a percentage formatted as a string. Works great if I exclude this record.

I know an UPDATE query would be more efficient but that hangs too. Anything I am missing?!

The Dest_rst is a very small SharePoint list.

Comment: Would a SQL Join not be easier?

Comment: Yep @Nathan_Sav! That hangs too! :-(

I am trying to debug my own problem by trying a different option but I am still stuck. At least this way I know what record is being difficult.

Comment: Does it still hang if you import the sharepoint list to a static table, it could be the sharepoint connection.

Comment: Works on a local table just fine. Also works on the SharePoint table fine except the one record (other 19 update fine)

Comment: Well, obviously there _is_ something special about record 3 ... you just haven't discovered yet what it is.

Comment: Paste the record from the working local table copy back over into the sharepoint record. Sounds like a rogue character / value or similar. Pasting it might remove it.

Comment: The plot thickens, edited my code to say `Dest_rst![Score] = "97.1%"`. No difference, still updates all records except one. Deleted record 3 completely and created a new record 24 and it hangs on that one instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my SharePoint list was just being an arse. Completely deleted the list from my DB, re-added it, all was well, sanity restored!